# segfault when calling fread()

Tags: c, file, fread

I just want to get read the first 8 bytes of a file and compared it with a 8 byte array to check if they are equal. But I am using fread() the system said I have a segmentation fault. I used print "HIHI" to see where it happened and before the fread line it shows but disappear when I put the printf after the freadline. Also, I tried to change the size of the buffer but the segfault still exist, can someone help? Here is my code.

```
const char PNG_FILE_FINGERPRINT[8] = { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a };
PNG * PNG_open(const char *filename, const char *mode) {
  
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(filename, mode);
  
  char buffer[100];
  printf("%s", "HIHI");
  size_t len = fread(buffer, 1, 8, fp);
  
  if (len != 8 || memcmp(buffer, PNG_FILE_FINGERPRINT, len) != 0) {
    return NULL;
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Always check the return value of function calls. `fopen` in particular in this case. Must not continue to `fread` if `fopen` fails.

Comment: Unrelated, but you're missing calls to `fclose`.

Comment: Also, `printf("%s", "HIHI")` is not a reliable way to debug. Because `printf` is line buffered by default so it may not have flushed to terminal before crashing (ie call may have been made but you did not see the result and thus reach wrong conclusions). Add a `"\n"` to the end of the string or better still use a debugger.

Comment: I also recommend stepping through with a debugger, but `std::cerr` is unbuffered and may work better for print debugging if you must.

Comment: So do you mean I need to check whether the fopen() function do gives me a file and then I use the fread function?

Comment: Yes of course. There are many reasons why `fopen` can fail and it is vital to check its result. Error checking is just standard good programming.

Comment: After the `fopen` call, add the check `if (fp == NULL) ...` and do something appropriate for that case.  If nothing else, at least, print an error message to stdout and exit with non-zero status.  Not making that check is a bug.

Comment: strongly suggest using a debugger so you know which line actually caused the seg fault event.